# How do I use a child class of a numpy type in numpy functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, polymorphism

I have this Python 3.8 program I'm using to make a Sudoku game for my own amusement, (code and notes at bottom). Many Sudoku utilities implement a way to add notes to a given cell in order to keep track of the game. I had chosen to implement my Sudoku board using `numpy`, however adding this noting ability requires me to add a `set` to each cell. I attempted to do this by creating a child class with a `set` bundled within to keep track of the notes.

This did not work however, as it appears that any type I attempt to use my class in any of `numpy`'s functions causes them to ignore my class and use the parent class instead. I tried even not making my class a subclass of any `numpy`'s types but that just caused it to use `object` as the type.

I tried using the `numpy.dtype` approach to create my own legitimate `dtype`, however, based on my understanding, I cannot embed a proper Python `set` within one of these. My other options would be to embed a static `N x 1` array within my custom dtype, (which I imagine is not particularly efficient), or to simply have another grid of cells to embed `sets` within. Neither of these seem particularly appealing to me.

Is there a way to do this with `numpy`, or is there a more appropriate method for my case?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np

class ByteWithSet(np.uint8):
    def __new__(cls, *_, **__):
        print("Creating new ByteWithSet")
        return super(ByteWithSet, cls).__new__(cls, *_, **__)
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing ByteWithSet")
        self._set = set()
    def is_fancy(self):
        return True

arr = np.zeros(shape=[2,2], dtype=ByteWithSet)
for el in arr.flatten():
    print(el, type(el))

for el in arr.flatten():
    print(el.is_fancy())

"""
This prints:
> 0 <class 'numpy.uint8'>
> 0 <class 'numpy.uint8'>
> 0 <class 'numpy.uint8'>
> 0 <class 'numpy.uint8'>

...Error stuff...
AttributeError: 'numpy.uint8' object has no attribute 'is_fancy'
"""
```

Comment: IMHO, you have 81 numbers and very simple operations, there is absolutely no need to use numpy. Pure python's lists would be more than enough.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I know this isn't the best excuse, but I really didn't want to implement row-column indexing, as I was feeling lazy. Is this worth salvaging or should I man up and not use `numpy`?

Comment: What do you mean by "row-column indexing"?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych being able to index rows and columns, `r1 = arr[1,:]; c2 = arr[:,2]`, without resorting to nested for loops, plus `numpy`'s slicing functionality is convenient